# PHP script logs in whether true or false

Tags: php, mysql

I am having troubles with a PHP login script which checks if you A.) Have registered then B.) Have you clicked the activation link (this is called active in my database)

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli, $active) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, hash, active 
                  FROM members 
                                  WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $active);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches 
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
                    if ($actve != 1){
                        return false;
                        header("location ../error.php?err=Account not activated");
                        exit();
                    }else{
                        return true;
                        header("location ../index.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                    // Login successful. 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct 
                    // We record this attempt in the database 
                    $now = time();
                    if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                        exit();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists. 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not create a prepared statement
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time 
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                                  FROM login_attempts 
                                  WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query. 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not create a prepared statement
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
}
```

yes, I know I am using a template from wikihow. But somewhere in the code even if I set active to 0 or 1 in MySQL it logs you in whatever the value is but has an error msg account not activated. I do not know if there is a return true/false statement missing and I have been troubleshooting for days with no avail.

Comment: **WARNING**: Never use a fast hash for passwords, that makes them easy to crack if your database ever gets leaked. You should be using a proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) method that's intentionally difficult and slow, like [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which uses Bcrypt by default. This also side-steps the need to generate your own cryptographically secure salt.

Comment: I know, but I am only using this for demonstration purposes to show myself that I can do this, I will develop it when I fix this.

Comment: There are possibly other problems, but the typo 'if ($actve != 1){' might not be helping.

Comment: @a09hopper You've created a bunch of work for yourself here by having two fields, by having to generate the salt, and who knows what else when `password_hash` does *all* of that for you. It's not just safer, it's a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how the login method is used it's hard to know for sure, but based on what you have shared the next thing I would try would be:

1. correct the typo `if ($actve != 1){`
2. Move the three calls that set `username` `user_id` and `login_string` on the `$_SESSION` in to the `else` block so that they only get set in the case of the password matching AND the `$active` variable being 1.

See what happens then.

Comment: Thanks, it is really hard to see a typo like that as it is 1 charcter off. Thanks so much